# SHA-3 maximal number of zeros (Padding)

Tags: padding, sha-3

What is the maximum number of zeros, which are appended at the input- padding in messages? How large must the message be for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the top and work down, using [FIPS 202](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) as reference. Note that the KECCAK paper uses a somewhat different notation (!).

$$\operatorname{SHA3-224}(M) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[448] (M | 01, 224)$$
$$\operatorname{SHA3-256}(M) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[512] (M | 01, 256)$$
$$\operatorname{SHA3-384}(M) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[768] (M | 01, 384)$$
$$\operatorname{SHA3-512}(M) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[1024] (M | 01, 512)$$

this is explained as:

> In each case, the capacity is double the digest length, i.e., $c = 2 \cdot d$, and the resulting input $N$ to $\operatorname{KECCAK}[c]$ is the message with the suffix appended, i.e, $N = M | 01$.

Now it is also given that

> $\operatorname{KECCAK}[c] = \operatorname{SPONGE}[\operatorname{KECCAK-p}[1600, 24], \operatorname{pad10*1}, 1600 – c]$.

where $\operatorname{SPONGE}$ is defined as $\operatorname{SPONGE}[f, pad, r]$. This means that $r = 1600 - c$ which can be rewritten as $r = 1600 - 2d$.

This is the information that we need for chapter 4: SPONGE CONSTRUCTION

> The padding rule, pad, is a function that produces padding, i.e., a string with an appropriate
> length to append to another string. In general, given a positive integer $x$ and a non-negative
> integer $m$, the output $\operatorname{pad}(x, m)$ is a string with the property that $m + \operatorname{len}(\operatorname{pad}(x, m))$ is a positive
> multiple of $x$. Within the sponge construction, $x = r$ and $m = \operatorname{len}(N)$, so that the padded input
> string can be partitioned into a sequence of $r$-bit strings. Algorithm 9 in Sec. 5.1 specifies the
> padding rule for the KECCAK functions and, hence, the SHA-3 functions.

Here $N$ is the input string of Keccak / SHA3 and $m$ is therefore the length of the input string (in bits).

So great, we now can finally look at the definition of $\operatorname{pad10*1}$:

> Within the sponge construction, $x = r$ and $m = \operatorname{len}(N)$
>
> 1. Let $j = (– m – 2) \bmod x$.
> 2. Return $P = 1 | 0^j | 1$.

Now negative modular calculations can be a bit confusing, but it is clear that no matter what, the maximum value of $j$ and thus the number of zero's is $x - 1$ or $r - 1$ as $x = r$. This is because $m$, the input length, can have any non-negative value. As this is for the sponge, this is also true for $\operatorname{KECCAK}[c]$ and therefore SHA3.

Now $m = \operatorname{len}(N)$ but $N = M|01$. In other words, the input $m$ is the message length - say $l$ - plus two bits. So that means that $j = (– m – 2) \bmod r = (– (l + 2) – 2) \bmod r = (–l - 2) – 2) \bmod r = -l - 4 \bmod r$. This maximum will be reached for $l = N \cdot r - 3$. This is kind of expected; if you have a minimal overhead of 4 bits for the padding then a message three bits shorter than the $r$ will require the maximum padding as the padding will overflow into the next block.

---

SHA3-224 means $r = 1600 - 448 = 1152$, so for $N \cdot 1152 - 3$ the maximum number of zero's is reached, which will be $r - 1 = 1151$ zero's.

Let's check this for $N = 1$: $\operatorname{len}(\{0,1\}^{1149}|01|1|0^{1151}|1) = 1149 + 1151 + 4 = 2304 = 2 \cdot 1152$. So that indeed leads to two times the rate $r$.

---

The usual input of hash algorithms isn't in bits, but in 8-bit bytes. In that case the input would simply be $N \cdot r$ for a maximum number of zero's that's of course $8 - 4 =4$ bits smaller. The number of zero *bytes* is of course $r / 8 - 2$ bytes.

Lets validate this again using SHA3-224. The first block of $r$ bytes would just be the message and the last block of $r$ bytes would consist of $06 | 00^{142} | 80$ in hexadecimals. This seems strange but that's because NIST uses little endian and flipped bit order (low order bits leftmost in the padding, but rightmost in the bytes, i.e. bit $b_7$ is on the right).

Answer (score 0):

SHA-3 has been formally defined in [FIPS 202](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) and in [its reference manual](http://keccak.noekeon.org/Keccak-reference-3.0.pdf).

> We define the sponge function denoted by $KECCAK[r,c]$ by applying the sponge construction as specified in *Algorithm 1* with $KECCAK-f[r+c]$, multi-rate padding and the bitrate $r$.
>   $$KECCAK[r,c] = SPONGE[KECCAK-f[r + c], pad10∗1, r]$$

The value $b = r + c$ is called the *width* of the state. It is either $25$, $50$, $100$, $200$, $400$, $800$ or $1600$.

> In the scope of the SHA-3 contest, we proposed the largest permutation, namely $KECCAK-f[1600]$.

So in our cases $b = 1600$.

The notation $\operatorname{SHA3-}x(M)$ produces a digest $x$ bits long and has a security claim $d = x$. Without going into details, $d$ can be seen as $c/2$.

Therefore in:

- $\operatorname{SHA3-224}(M)$, $c = 2\times224 = 448$ and $r = 1600 - c = 1152$
- $\operatorname{SHA3-256}(M)$, $c = 2\times256 = 512$ and $r = 1600 - c = 1088$
- $\operatorname{SHA3-384}(M)$, $c = 2\times384 = 768$ and $r = 1600 - c = 832$
- $\operatorname{SHA3-512}(M)$, $c = 2\times512 = 1024$ and $r = 1600 - c = 576$

Hence:

- $\operatorname{SHA3-224}(M) = KECCAK[1152,448]$
- $\operatorname{SHA3-256}(M) = KECCAK[1088,512]$
- $\operatorname{SHA3-384}(M) = KECCAK[832,768]$
- $\operatorname{SHA3-512}(M) = KECCAK[576,1024]$

As the speed of the algorithm is directly related to $r$ (bit rate absorption), the higher the security, the slower the function will be.

From the [reference](http://keccak.noekeon.org/Keccak-reference-3.0.pdf):

> KECCAK makes use of the multi-rate padding.
>
> **Definition 1.** Multi-rate padding, denoted by $pad10∗1$, appends a single bit 1 followed by the minimum number of bits 0 followed by a single bit 1 such that the length of the result is a multiple of the block length.
>
> Multi-rate padding appends at least 2 bits and at most the number of bits in a block plus one.

**TL;DR: you already have your answer: at most you will append a bit 1 followed by $r-1$ bits 0 followed by a bit 1.**

The idea here is to split a message $m$ into blocks of $r$ bits (bit rate). 3 cases arise:

1. $|m| = x \times r$.
   Here it will append a bit 1, $r-2$ bits 0 and a bit 1 in order to get a full block.
2. $|m| = x \times r + q$ where $q = r - 1$.
   This case happen because we need to append at least 2 bits. So we first complete the block with a bit 1 and then we add another full block of r bits: $r - 1$ bits 0 and the last bit 1. So in this case we have $r - 1$ bits 0.
3. $|m| = x \times r + q$ where $q > 0$ and $q \le r -2$.
   We just complete the last block with a bit 1 followed by $(r - q) - 2$ bits 0 and the last bit at 1.

So the biggest number of bits 0 you can append is $r - 1$:

- $\operatorname{SHA3-224}(M) = KECCAK[1152,448] \Rightarrow 1|0^{1151}|1$.
- $\operatorname{SHA3-256}(M) = KECCAK[1088,512] \Rightarrow 1|0^{1087}|1$.
- $\operatorname{SHA3-384}(M) = KECCAK[832,768] \Rightarrow 1|0^{831}|1$.
- $\operatorname{SHA3-512}(M) = KECCAK[576,1024] \Rightarrow 1|0^{575}|1$.

Comment: `SHA3-224(M) = KECCAK[448] (M || 01, 224);` -> those two bits are not the padding, they are the suffix for domain separation. The padding consists of an additional $1|0^*|1$. This padding is *not* dependent on the additional bits for the domain separation. Also, if you have 1152 bits set to 0 then one of the 0 bits is in the previous block. That should not be necessary. You're forgetting the starting 1 bit it seems.

Comment: yup you might be right. Will triple check this after diner. :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes corrected, forgot the leading 1 (and yes I ignored the domain separation).

Comment: But the question was about the message size *for SHA3*, not KECCAK. In that case you cannot just ignore the domain separation.