# Using a bit sequence of zeros followed by one byte in Keccak

Tags: padding, sha-3, keccak

For what purpose it is not right to use a bit sequence of 2000+ zeros followed by one byte in Keccak? Is there a possible application of such input for Keccak? If yes, after which transformation?

Comment: You might want to provide some context for this question - as stated, it doesn't make a great deal of sense...

Comment: @poncho Basically, I have a sequence of 3064 zeros followed by 00010000 and the original question was "for which cryptographic protocol/purpose this sequence could/could not be used". I believe that using that sequence as padding of a message that will be hashed with Keccak is a bad idea. I don't know when such a sequence can be used in the algorithm though.

Comment: "I believe that using that sequence as padding of a message that will be hashed with Keccak is a bad idea" - what cryptographical weakness would you suspect (and why)?  And, why wouldn't that sequence be used with Keccak; it accepts any bitstring as input, and that input does fall under the category of "any bit string"

Comment: @poncho I'm talking about the multi-rate padding in the sponge function. Per my understanding, it is a feasibility problem. The number of zeros in the padding depends on the rate (number of zeros = r-1). [https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37304/sha-3-maximal-number-of-zeros-padding]